# Error doing region computations on Hexahedrons

Tags: regions

I have the following set of points which I use to define a Hexahedron and compute the RegionCentroid

```
pt = {{-13, -13, 32}, {13, -13, 32}, {13, 13, 32}, {-13, 13,32}, {-13, -13, 41}, {13, -13, 41}, {13, 13, 41}, {-13, 13, 41}};
RegionCentroid[Hexahedron[pt]]
[out]: {0, 0, 73/2}
```

When I add 0.25 to all the coordinates, the centroid shifts by 0.25 in all directions as expected :

```
pt = 0.25 + {{-13, -13, 32}, {13, -13, 32}, {13, 13, 32}, {-13, 13, 
 32}, {-13, -13, 41}, {13, -13, 41}, {13, 13, 41}, {-13, 13, 41}};
RegionCentroid[Hexahedron[pt]]
[out]: {0.25, 0.25, 36.75}
```

However, if I add 0.2 to all coordinates, it gives me an error :

```
pt = 0.2 + {{-13, -13, 32}, {13, -13, 32}, {13, 13, 32}, {-13, 13,32}, {-13, -13, 41}, {13, -13, 41}, {13, 13, 41}, {-13, 13, 41}};
RegionCentroid[Hexahedron[pt]]
[out]: RegionCentroid::reg: Hexahedron[{{-12.8,-12.8,32.2},{13.2,-12.8,32.2},{13.2,13.2,32.2},{-12.8,13.2,32.2},{-12.8,-12.8,41.2},{13.2,-12.8,41.2},{13.2,13.2,41.2},{-12.8,13.2,41.2}}] is not a correctly specified region.
```

When I check the validity of the region, it seems to be fine :

```
RegionQ[Hexahedron[pt]]
[out]: True
```

I checked by adding different offsets to my list of points and sometimes it works and sometimes it gives the same error.

I don't see what I am doing wrong here or why it does not work for some list of Hexahedron coordinates.

I am running Mathematica 11.1.1.0 on OS X 10.12.8

Comment: You're looking for a workaround or an explanation of the bug? Anyway, you may want to use an arbitrary-precision number for now, such as `2/10` instead of `0.2`.

Comment: @Taiki - a rational number like 2/10 is an **exact** number, i.e., it has infinite precision, An arbitrary precision number would be 0.2`20 which also works in this case.

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon for the correction :)